# How to create an universal linebreak replacement in Sphinx that works in HTML, LaTeX and other builders?

Tags: html, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm generating my documentation with Sphinx on ReadTheDocs. Sometime a hard linebreak is required. Such a linebreak can be created with the `raw` directive:

```
.. |br| raw:: html

   <br />
```

I can create a similar linebreak for LaTeX:

```
.. |br| replace:: \linebreak
```

I created a `prolog.inc` file, that is read from disk and stored in the `rst_prolog` variable of Sphinx's `conf.py`:

```
# reST settings
prologPath = "prolog.inc"
try:
  with open(prologPath, "r") as prologFile:
    rst_prolog = prologFile.read()
except Exception as ex:
  print("[ERROR:] While reading '{0!s}'.".format(prologPath))
  print(ex)
  rst_prolog = ""
```

**Idea 1 - Switch the prolog files based on the builder name**
Unfortunately, I can't switch the prolog file, because a `conf.py` doesn't know the selected `buildername`.

**Idea 2 - Use the `only` directive**

I tried this:

```
.. only:: html
   .. |br| raw:: html

      <br />

.. only:: latex
   .. |br| replace:: \linebreak
```

And I tired this:

```
.. |br| replace::
   .. only:: html
      .. raw:: html

         <br />

   .. only:: latex

      \linebreak
```

Unfortunately, Sphinx doesn't support replacements and/or `raw` directives in an `only` directive.

**Question:**
Any ideas on how to create a single replacement like `|br|` that works in HTML, LaTeX and maybe other builders?

---

**Edit**

Ok I found 50% of a way to overwrite `rst_prolog`. I added a `setup` function to the `conf.py` file. Here I can change some configuration options. But how?

```
def setup(app):
  prolog = app.config.values['rst_prolog']
  print(prolog)
  builder = app.buildername
  if (builder in ("html", "latex")):
    print(os.getcwd())                             # we are now in 'docs/_build'
    prologPath = "../prolog.{0}.inc".format(builder)
    try:
      with open(prologPath, "r") as prologFile:
        rst_prolog = prologFile.read()

      app.config.values['rst_prolog'] = (prolog[0], prolog[1], [rst_prolog])
      print(app.config.values['rst_prolog'])
    except Exception as ex:
      print("[ERROR:] While reading '{0!s}'.".format(prologPath))
      print(ex)
```

What is the required format of a configuration value in `app.config`?

```
>>> print(app.config.values['rst_prolog'])
(None, 'env', [<class 'str'>])
```